# How to Download Spreadsheet from Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have the complete link, as well as the file_id for a particular file on my google drive. Its a large spreadsheet with dozens of tabs, and this file is viewable publically. Im trying to download it in the correct format. Ive tried using a half dozen different api calls with the google Drive API, as well as python's Requests module. Im able to return a file object and even the text of the first page of the file, but i havent been able to properly convert that text to anything usable. below are examples of different methods ive attempted:

```
response = requests.get(google_url)
# returns the html content of only the first tab
```

Ive also tried the code below which works, but i dont see the output of any downloaded file/s

```
    request = service.files().export_media(
    fileId=file_id, mimeType='text/csv')
    fh = FileIO('cow.xlsx', mode='wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

The expected output is simply the entire spreadsheet to be downloaded to my default downloads folder as a complete xlsx file. Any help with explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the results of your attempt?  do you have an error?

Comment: If you want to save it as an xlsx why are you exporting it using the mime type of csv?

Comment: i think ive switched mimetypes several times, so the one in this code is just one of the ones ive tried. i'll see which mimetype fits this need, and then proceed.

Comment: Please submit a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and the exact error.  We cant help you fix random code we need the exact code you are having a problem with

Comment: I think that in your script shown in your question, when the value of `mimeType` is modified to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`, the script works. When `mimeType='text/csv'` is used, the file of `cow.xlsx` including the CSV data is created. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So when you modify your script like above, what result will you obtain? If I misunderstood your current issue, I apologize.

Comment: Hi ! According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats) the mime type ```text/csv``` will only work for the first sheet of the Spreadsheet. So I believe as @Tanaike mentioned the right format should be the one corresponding to ```MS Excel```. Could you try changing it and let us know how it went ? Thanks ! :D